# Problems grouping has_many through collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having a problems with :group and :uniq tags as an option to has_many through collection definition. I have many triple model associations defined on my system and I want to list elements grouped to avoid (the actual) repetition. My main model looks like that:

```
class Trip < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :agent
  has_many :trips_destinations, :class_name => "TripsDestination"
  has_many :destinations, :through => :trips_destinations

  has_and_belongs_to_many :vibes, join_table: :trips_vibes
  has_and_belongs_to_many :verbs, join_table: :trips_verbs

  has_many :trips_destinations_activities, :class_name => "TripsDestinationsActivity"
  has_many :activities, :through => :trips_destinations_activities, :uniq => true

  has_many :trips_destinations_hotels, :class_name => "TripsDestinationsHotel"
  has_many :hotels, :through => :trips_destinations_hotels

  has_many :trips_destinations_recommended_places, :class_name => "TripsDestinationsRecommendedPlace"
  has_many :recommended_places, :through => :trips_destinations_recommended_places

  has_many :trips_destinations_transportations, :class_name => "TripsDestinationsTransportation"
  has_many :transportations, :through => :trips_destinations_transportations

...
...

end
```

Anyone know how to list they why avoiding repetition given the pair [trip_id, destination_id]?
And why they are repeated?

My rails version is 4 and I the image below shows the error message when passing grouping options to has_many relation.

[image]

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax for uniq is not correct for Rails 4.

```
has_many :activities, -> { uniq }, :through => :trips_destinations_activities
```

Unique now has [scope syntax](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#scopes-for-has-and-belongs-to-many).

Comment: Thanks @eabraham. Are you in a chat, skype or something like that? I fix this, but now I'm having some doubts with the triple model association.

Comment: By triple model do you mean a many-to-many relationship? If so, try modeling it like [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. By triple model association i understand a model which holds links to 3 different models. Modeled into the DB in that way: trip_id | destination_id | activity_id. I'm modeling this as you suggest in the guide but I can't get some things working.